# Red Hat with rpc.statd is not running and can't start nfslock

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I try to mount from Linux machine to some folder on a Windows machine.

From the output I see that mount complains about `rpc.statd`. So I tried to start the `nfslock` but I got `FAILED`.

Then I look on the `nfslock` script and I see that its failed on the command:

```
 pidof -c -o 1949 -o 1626 -o %PPID -x rpc.statd
```

This command should return some process ID, but this command does not print any process ID.

So how to start `nfslock`?

```
 /etc/init.d]#  mount 10.15.22.21:/work11/AAPL /mnt

 mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
 mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
 mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified

 /etc/init.d]# ./nfslock start
 Starting NFS statd:                                        [FAILED]

 /etc/init.d]#  pidof -c -o 1949 -o 1626 -o %PPID -x rpc.statd
 /etc/init.d]# echo $?
 1
```